# DiagrammeR: Create graph from minimal node and edge data frame

Tags: r, diagrammer

I'm trying to use the `DiagrammeR` package to create a graph based on two simple data frames created by hand. The resulting graph should simply have two nodes ('a' and 'b') and one edge connecting them ('a' -> 'b').

Based on the documentation, it seems like this should be very easy to do.
From the package documentation as of version 1.0.1, the following are the minimal inputs to the `create_graph()` function:

> `nodes_df`: an optional data frame containing, at minimum, a column
>   (called id) which contains node IDs for the graph. Additional columns
>   (node attributes) can be included with values for the named node
>   attribute.
>
> `edges_df`: an optional data frame containing, at minimum, two columns
>   (called from and to) where node IDs are provided. Additional columns
>   (edge attributes) can be included with values for the named edge
>   attribute.

Based on this documentation, it seems like at least one of the following two attempts to define a graph should work:

```
library(Diagrammer)
options('stringsAsFactors' = FALSE)

# Using integer node IDs
create_graph(nodes_df = data.frame(id = c(1L, 2L)),
             edges_df = data.frame(from = 1L, to = 2L))

# Using character node IDs
create_graph(nodes_df = data.frame(id = c('a', 'b')),
             edges_df = data.frame(from = 'a', to = 'b'))
```

However, with both attempts to create a graph, I receive the following error message:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(nodes_df, , i) : undefined columns selected
```

Why do the calls not work as expected? What is the minimal way to create the intended graph by creating node and edge data frames using just the `data.frame()` function, similar to the example given here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood well enough your problem, but, I think it's maybe better to use `create_node_df` and `crete_edge_df` instead of using `data.frame` function. I gave you an example while using this package:

```
l1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
l2 <- c("b", "c", "d")

# find all the unique nodes
all<- unique(union(l1, l2))
all

#creating a node data frame
nodes<- create_node_df(n= length(all),
                    style= "filled",
                    label= all,
                    color= "lightblue",
                    shape= "box")


 # data frame of edges
edges<-create_edge_df(from = match(l1, all),
                  to=match(l2, all),
                  label = all,
                  rel= "related",
                  color= "black")
edges
graph<-create_graph(nodes, edges)
render_graph(graph)
```

Cheers.